# Is "as that of drugs can do* or "as that of WHAT drugs can do" correct?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Could anybody tell me which one of the following sentences is correct?

1. The issue is that an abuse of "kratom" leaves can have the same deleterious **effect as that of drugs can do**.
2. The issue is that an abuse of "kratom" leaves can have the same deleterious **effect as that of what drugs can do**.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better rephrase would be this:

**The issue is that abuse of "Kratom" leaves can have the same deleterious effects as drug abuse.**

"An abuse" is not idiomatic, because "abuse" is an ongoing thing.

"That of what drugs can do" is hard to parse, but because the writer in the comments indicated that he wanted to emphasize the parallelism of "abuse" it would be better to just include the word twice instead of writing around it with wordy clauses. In the rewritten sentence, the implied portion dropped off the end is "can have."

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not a fan of either sentence; however, no. 2 is correct.  I would personally not say or write it so wordily; I would say or write it like this:

> The issue is that an abuse of "kratom" leaves can have the same
>   deleterious effects **as drugs can have**.

Comment: But i want to emphasize on the abuse that s why i put that of which refers to an abuse of. This is because with the word abuse, drugs can have positive effects

Comment: I'm not a fan of either sentence either. I'd say: "The issue is that an abuse of "kratom" leaves can have the same deleterious effect as that of drugs." or  "The issue is that an abuse of "kratom" leaves can have the same deleterious effects as those of drugs."

Comment: ....or simply: "The issue is that an abuse of "kratom" leaves can have the same deleterious effects as drugs." or "The issue is that an abuse of "kratom" leaves can have the same deleterious effects as drugs do."

Comment: Those examples are fine as well and better than the original ones above.

Comment: This concept is the same as "he can do better than i can do" and "he can do better than me"  so  that is why i think "an abuse of Kratom leaves can have the same deleterious effects as that of drug can do" is acceptable

Comment: Well, technically, "he can do better than me" is not grammatically correct although it is said by many native speakers. The reason is that "than", in this case, is a conjunction and not a preposition.